# How to build a classifier with a rejection class

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Let's say I need to build a food classifier, and I want a rejection class for the inputs that are not food.

What is the best way to do that? 
Should I just add a new class label that includes pictures of anything but food? Is there a best way to chose which pictures I should use?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to do that? Should I just add a new class label that includes pictures of anything but food?

Adding a new class which can be called *none* is a thing that is usual for such tasks.

> Is there a best way to chose which pictures I should use?

Yes, you should pick the images of the *none* type from the real distribution that your classifier is going to face while test time. It means all the classes should have a same distribution while training and testing. It should be satisfied even for the none class. For instance, suppose that your none type class can be a human hand or a table or something like that. You should not put an elephant image for none type because you are not going to have an elephant in your kitchen.